# JQUERY how to select items

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to select some items and check if value are not empty, and hide the previus item....but not work....

for example:

```
<script>
    if($('input[type=text],input[type=email],input[type=password]').val() != ""){
    $(this). prev().hide();
    }
</script>

<div class="prova"></div>
<input type="text">

<div class="prova"></div>
<input type="text">

<div class="prova"></div>
<input type="text">
```

when i load page the previus div for every input, not hide....someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by passing a function to `.val()`.

```
var inputs = $('input[type=text],input[type=email],input[type=password]');

inputs.val(function(i,curr_val){
    if( curr_val )
        $(this).prev('.prova').hide();
    return curr_val;
});
```

Comment: This way is better if your prime requirement is to set the value of elements which is not the case of OP.

Answer (score 2):

When you call a call `val()` method on a set of matched elements it gets the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements. So you should run a loop check the value of each element and then hide previous element. Try this.

```
$('input[type]').each(function(){
   if($(this).val()){
      $(this).prev().hide();
   }
});
```

If you have to show the previous element if there is value then you can use this script.

```
$('input[type]').each(function(){
    $(this).prev().toggle($(this).val() == '');
});
```

`.toggle(showOrHide)` - Display or hide the element based on the boolean input.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this:

```
$(':input').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $(this).prev().hide();
  }
});
```